# Database Migration

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, migration

We are migrating our one of testing servers.

**My questions are:**

1. What is a best way to migrate database from one server to another?
2. If I do data migration through export/import utility (Full database export) then will it create schema and table spaces or it will import whole dump in one table space?
3. If I use impdp will it create user grants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no best method. It all depends on the circumstances: size of the database, downtime allowed, version difference, platform difference.
2. It will create the tablespaces and schemas. The tablespaces can be changed with the `REMAP_TABLESPACE` parameter.
3. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

> What is a best way to migrate database from one server to another?

When I have done this in the past migrating a production db to another server, where we could only have down time of a matter of minutes. I did it by log shipping. For the final log I cut off all applications etc, did the final log backup shipped across restored and brought the other db online.

Answer (score 0):

## Restore from Backup

If the maintenance window allows it:  restore the database from backup with RMAN.

This ensures that your Backup and Restore procedures are actually working.